# VirtualHosts with Apache not respecting ServerName

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, virtualhost

This has always bugged me and I've never got around to figuring out why Apache does this, I always resorted to the mod_vhost plugin to work around the issue.

Basically, I have 2 vhosts in sites-enabled (Ubuntu server), their contents:

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosta.domain.com/"
ServerName vhosta.domain.com
<Directory "/var/www/vhosta.domain.com/">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhostb.domain.com/"
ServerName vhostb.domain.com
<Directory "/var/www/vhostb.domain.com/">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now logically these 2 would be accessible separately, however it seems that all requests to my server, no matter what vhosts I define on top of this, are going to vhosta.domain.com.

Am I missing something incredibly obvious? I really don't get why it's doing this..

Thanks

Comment: Where are you defining this vhosts ? In separate files in /etc/apache2/sites-available ? Are you generating the apropiate links in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a NameVirtualhost; however:

- DO NOT use VirtualHost *; use `VirtualHost *:80` instead.

The following is the correct way:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  Servername vhosta
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  Servername vhostb
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity (and I always used *:port myself) - why do you discourage the use of "*" ?

Comment: The apache documentation does. This causes unexpected behaviour when you are listening on more than 1 port.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I'm surprised webmin does not add this automatically, or Ubuntu for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

Before your virtual host definitions, you need something like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

You're doing name-based virtual hosts.  See the documentation here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost